# How to access List Items in a list

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to display the ListItems in a gridview.

Please help me in finding a way to access the list items.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://mysitehere......"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList list = web.Lists["TestList"];
        .......
        .......
    }
}
```

Please help me in accessing the list item values.

Answer (score 7):

The below code should do the trick, get the full [article from msdn here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.aspx)

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://mysitehere......"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList list = web.Lists["TestList"];
        SPListItemCollection collListItems = list.Items;
        foreach (SPListItem oListItem in collListItems)
        {
           string value = SPEncode.HtmlEncode(oListItem["Field1_Name"]);
           // do something with value
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You may use any of the below:

```
        SPList list;
        foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
        {
            string title = item["Title"];
        }

        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
        query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title'/>";
        SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
        foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
        {
            string title = item["Title"];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Items.Count; i++ )
        {
            string title = list.Items[i]["Title"];
        }
```

From the performance point of view, I suggest using the SP Query as then you can specify which fields to fetch and whether or not to fetch any associated metadata with the list items. This results in fewer db calls.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 3):

Use [SPDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spdatasource.aspx) to display list items in a grid view, i.e. create and configure an SPDataSource object and bind it to a [SPGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spgridview.aspx) control.

Answer (score 2):

For displaying items in a gridview (if you don't want to use SPGridView), I would use the [GetDataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemcollection.getdatatable.aspx) method, instead of using a foreach loop as many of the answers do.

```
if (items.Count > 0)
{
    DataTable dt = items.GetDataTable();
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I haven't done any sharepoint work, but I believe you can use:

```
foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
```

or

```
foreach (SPListItem item in list.GetItems(view)) // or query
```

or access by index or guid:

```
SPListItem item = list.Items[10];
SPListItem item = list.Items[guid];
```

Comment: The is correct, however there's a limitation in SharePoint's architecture when using SPList.Items - it causes all items to retrieved from the content database on each call and then the enumerator is returned.

The recommendation is to assing list.Items to a variable and then loop on the variable, so

foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)

becomes

SPListItemCollection listItems = list.Items;
foreach (SPListItem item in listItems)

Comment: @dariom: There's no difference in that code. A foreach loop will only execute the initializing part once.

Answer (score 1):

The SPQuery approach as suggested by unknown(yahoo) is the way to go, however you should remember that the default rowlimit of SPQuery is 100:

```
try
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(theURL))
            {
                SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
                SPList list = web.Lists["TheNameOfTheList"];

                //search each ListItem where the date is after 1/1 2009
                SPQuery query = new SPQuery();

                //the default is 100, which is less then the expected max
                query.RowLimit = 500;

                // The U2U CAML Query builder rules :-)
                query.Query = "<Where><Gt><FieldRef Name='StartDate' /><Value Type='DateTime'>";
                query.Query += "2009-01-01T00:00:00Z</Value></Gt></Where>";
                SPListItemCollection resultset = list.GetItems(query);
                foreach (SPListItem item in resultset)
                {
                    // do something  
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you´re using .NET 3.5 I would recommend using the linq datasource together with the spgridview to bind splistitems to a gridview. Saves you a lot of time. 
I have an [example](http://johanleino.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!6BE273C70C45B5D1!328.entry) of this on my blog.
To display images you have to get the url of the image. Here is an example of that:

```
SPListItem item = GetItem();
string imagefieldhtml = item["NameOfImageField"].ToString();
ImageFieldValue imagefield = new ImageFieldValue(imagefieldhtml);

var url = imagefield.ImageUrl;
```

The url variable will now hold the image url.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have solved the above issue. In my case I did not need to use the SPEncode.HTML, so I have commented out everything that's not needed. Here is the fixed code if anyone else needs it:

```
using (SPSite site3 = SPContext.Current.Site)
{
    using (SPWeb web2 = site3.OpenWeb())
    {

        // SPWeb site3 = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb;
        SPList list2 = web2.Lists["Configuration"];
        SPListItemCollection collListItems = list2.Items;

        foreach (SPListItem oListItem in list2.Items)
        {
            //string value = SPEncode.HtmlEncode.ToString(oListItem["List name"]);
            string valueListName = oListItem["List name"].ToString();
            string valueListURL = oListItem["List URL"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```