# Accessing a SPListItem from SPListItemCollection directly

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I have a SPList object and use SPList.Items to get the SPListItemCollection. From this collection I need to access one SPListItem for which the UniqueID or GUID is not know. Is it possible to access the element directly using Display Name or any other information (other than GUID or UniqueId). Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not out of the box - see the question [How to access List Items in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828034/how-to-access-list-items-in-a-list) for the options. Retrieving the information with **[SPQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.aspx)** is recommended to avoid placing too much load on the database. There is more information on how to use that in my answer to [SharePoint : Check if item exists in a list, minimum overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340444/sharepoint-check-if-item-exists-in-a-list-minimum-overhead):

A good alternative is to use **LINQ**. This option has been provided by the community (Keith Dahlby and Wictor Wilén) and is available in the [SharePoint Extensions Lib](http://spexlib.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Hi, I use this query to find the items on the basis of DisplayName. "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name = 'DisplayName'/><Value Type='Text'>documenting</Value></Eq></Where>";But it throws an error stating that 'one or more fields are not properly installed. Is it possible to find items based on their DisplayName.

Comment: http://www.sharepoint-tips.com/2007/04/one-of-more-field-types-are-not.html

Maybe You should try changing DisplayName to Title ?

Comment: Janis is right - you should be using <FieldRef Name='Title'/>

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use CAML then the [CAML Query Builder](http://www.u2u.be/res/Tools/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx) is really helpful. Personally I don't like doing CAML using a plain old string so I've been using [CAML.NET](http://www.codeplex.com/camldotnet) to wrap CAML queries